# How do I change focus between editor and actual keyboard in android sample softkeyboard?

Tags: android

I am trying to modify the code of android sample soft keyboard to get the focus on keyboard. Currently the focus is on the editor box and I can't have the focus on keyboard.The keys have focus only if I press it. But I am trying to get default focus on the keyboard(could be any key) so that I can select the keys with external keyboards arrow keys. Is it possible? I would b glad if someone can help me on this :).

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely

Chandan

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is possible, as the soft keyboard is not part of your activity's layout.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But is there any chance to get the focus on the board along with the focus on EditText? I mean there is a keyboard named hacker keyboard. I fetched the code from repository but still could not figure out how to get the focus on keys. It has 4 arrow keys but they do the same thing as external hard arrow keys do with the EditText field. It does not change the focus on it's keys. If you find any idea, please post. But again thank you. :)